# endMethod never called in TaskFactory<T>.FromAsync()

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have the following Silverlight code.

```
Container container = new Container("http://localhost:8080/odata");
DataServiceQuery dsq = container.MyEntity;
IEnumerable result = Task<IEnumerable>.Factory.FromAsync(dsq.BeginExecute, dsq.EndExecute, null).Result;
```

The problem I am experiencing is that `dsq.EndExecute` is never called.  I watched the HTTP traffic in Fiddler and the request to `http://localhost:8080/odata/MyEntity` goes out and the response below is received. The Task just doesn't seem to acknowledge that a response was received.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
Date: Mon, 20 May 2013 15:04:16 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
DataServiceVersion: 3.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 562
Connection: Close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="http://localhost:8080/odata/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" 
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" 
    xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <id>http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/</id>
  <title />
  <updated>2013-05-20T15:04:16Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" href="http://localhost:8080/odata/MyEntity" />
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
</feed>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does result end up with any value?
How do you know **dsg.EndExecute** is never called?
Have you tried to wrap **dsg.EndExecute** to set a breakpoint there?

Comment: I have tried wrapping it in an anonymous function and setting a break point.  It's never hit and Result never returns at all.  It's just stuck waiting for a response that has already come.

Comment: Even if you were calling form a UI thread I would expect it to Block the UI but not to dead lock.
I expect that, if **dsg.EndExecute** isn't called the task will never complete and you never get a result, right?

Comment: If you call it the old fashioned way, will **dsg.EndExecute** be called?
If you call it synchronously, will it complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this problem by just avoiding `FromAsync()` all together.  The following code works for me.

```
var result = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => dsq.BeginExecute(null, null))
    .ContinueWith(t => dsq.EndExecute(t.Result)).Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `Result`. You should `await` the result instead. In many situations, `Result` will deadlock a GUI application (including Silverlight).

I explain this deadlock more fully [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [in an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: While this is true, I'm not concerned with blocking the UI thread at this point.  I'm just trying to get a value back.  Haven't been able to get that to work yet.

Comment: Did you read the links I posted? I'm not talking about *blocking;* I'm talking about *deadlock.*

Comment: I see. I misunderstood. I thought you were referring to blocking the UI thread.  I have a dilemma, though. The async call to my WCF service is being made within an implementation of *TResult IQueryProvider.Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)* so I don't think I have the option to make this method async.  What do you recommend?

Comment: In that situation, it shouldn't cause a deadlock. The deadlock I described only happens if you block on an `async` method, which you don't have. If you remove the `Result` and put trace/breakpoint inside a `ContinueWith` instead, is it ever hit?

Comment: No, the endMethod `dsq.EndExecute()` is never called so nothing after that ever executes.  Doesn't matter if it's `.Result` or `.ContinueWith()`.

Comment: Are you using a custom proxy or doing anything weird with the channel?

Comment: I don't think so.  The only thing I can think of that's out of the ordinary is that I don't have a WCF Data Service server side.  I'm using `System.Web.Http.OData.EntitySetController<T>` in ASP.NET Web API, but I believe this shouldn't matter as Web API now implements a fully-functional OData interface.

Comment: I haven't used OData since the old days. I recommend you copy this additional information into your question, and I'm going to withdraw this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding async/await?

```
public async void foo()
{
   IEnumerable result = await Task<IEnumerable>.Factory.FromAsync(
      dsq.BeginExecute, dsq.EndExecute, null);
}
```